# fullpage.js - setting responsiveWidth and scrollOverflow breaks page on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

**CONTEXT**

I am using fullpage.js on a page and would like to disable it on mobile, as some sections do not fit within a single screen on mobile devices (they are just cut off). I've found that setting `responsiveWidth: 1000` and `scrollOverflow: true` has the intended effect.

**Problem**

However, setting these options also seems to move the entire page up by a screen and a half - i.e. the top 1.5 screens worth of content is invisible, and the page only starts near the middle of section 2. Has anyone experienced this bug before?

Any particular reason I might be seeing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `scrollOverflow`, in fact, I always suggest people not to use it. That's not a real responsive site!

You can use the `responsiveWidth` and `responsiveHeight` options and then force the section to be as big as you want by doing this:

```
.fp-responsive .fp-section,
.fp-responsive .fp-slide,
.fp-responsive .fp-tableCell{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

I used the class `.fp-responsive` which is one of the [state classes added to the `body` by fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs). It will be added when the plugin fires the responsive mode and it provides a way to create conditional CSS styles.

Comment: Thank you - this seems to work well well as long as I also give each section a min-height (otherwise some sections disappear). However, opening a slide within a section scrolls user back to section1 - any way to fix this?

Comment: All slides within a section have to be of the same height.

Comment: This has been resolved - the only issue left is that as I'm scrolling away from a section (with autoScrolling disabled), when I'm about 30% out of the section, the section I'm leaving changes slides... any idea what might be triggering this?